# iOS SpringBoard property badgeNumberOrString not found on object of id

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, logos

So I'm trying to set the app badge for a particular app by bundle ID. I've hooked into SpringBoard and set *all* apps to a specific string before this, but I can't seem to find a way to set the badge string for a single application icon. The error I'm getting thrown currently is:

```
Tweak.xm:28:123: error: property 'badgeNumberOrString' not found on object of
      type 'id'
  ...applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.AppStore"].badgeNumberOrStri..
                                                            ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [/home/theodd/Desktop/appbadge/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/Tweak.xm.94fb86bd.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/theodd/Desktop/appbadge/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/AppBadge.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [AppBadge.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

My current code in Tweak.xm is:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
#define PLIST_PATH @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.theodd.appbadge.plist"

inline bool GetPrefBool(NSString *key){
    return [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH] valueForKey:key] boolValue];
}

inline NSString* GetPrefString(NSString *key){
    return [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH] objectForKey:key];
}

inline NSString* appID(NSString *key) {
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:key];
}

@interface SBApplicationIcon : NSObject
- (void)setBadge:(id)arg1;
@end

@interface SBApplicationController : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (id)applicationWithBundleIdentifier:(id)arg1;
@end

BOOL isEnabled = GetPrefBool(@"enableSwitch");
NSString* bString = GetPrefString(@"badgeName");

NSString* appStoreString = [SBApplicationController.sharedInstance applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.AppStore"].badgeNumberOrString;

%hook SBApplication
- (id)badgeNumberOrString {
    id r = %orig;
    if(isEnabled) return bString;
    return r;
}

%end
```

EDIT: I noticed that I should be separating the SBApplicationIcon.sharedInstance from the applicationWithBundleIdentifier, etc. and piecing it together like so:

```
that = SBApplicationController.sharedInstance,
then this = [that applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@""],
this.badgeNumberOrString = @""
```

But I'm not sure what object types I should save them to. I'm still very new to the logos/objective-c environment. I have experience in C++ and Java/javaScript so I understand programming basic ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with SpringBoard.

You've defined badgeNumberOrString as a method, not as a property.

If you add it in SBApplicationController like:

```
@interface SBApplicationController : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (id)applicationWithBundleIdentifier:(id)arg1;

@property NSString *badgeNumberOrString;

@end
```

It'll be set accordingly, and you can go on with overriding the getter.

If you wanted to use method-wise, you need to use brackets just like in your other methods:

```
NSString* appStoreString = [[SBApplicationController.sharedInstance applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.AppStore"] badgeNumberOrString];
```

But this line would still not be working since you're trying to access a property -which is not available- and set its value:

```
this.badgeNumberOrString = @""
```

Comment: Is there any way that I could access the badgeNumberOrString property and modify it inside of the hook?

Comment: SBApplicationController is inheriting from NSObject, which doesn't have bagdeNumberOfString property. Hence, you need to create that property yourself.